# Waveform being created in the wrong div

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm recording audio and then saving the clips on the page with the waveform attached to it (Using WaveSurfer.js), but the waveform is being placed in the first div with the classname waveform.

rec.onstop = e => {
    console.log("Recorder stopped");

```
var trackName = prompt("Enter a name for your sound clip");

var trackContainer = document.createElement("article");
var trackLabel = document.createElement("p");
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
var waveDiv = document.createElement("div");
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

trackContainer.classList.add("tracks");
waveDiv.setAttribute("class", "waveform");
audio.setAttribute("class", "clip");
deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
trackLabel.innerHTML = trackName;
trackLabel.setAttribute("class", "track-label");

var btnDiv = document.createElement("div");
var playBtn = document.createElement("button");
var pauseBtn = document.createElement("button");
var play = document.createElement("img");
var pause = document.createElement("img");




btnDiv.setAttribute("class", "btn-div");
playBtn.setAttribute("class", "func-btns");
pauseBtn.setAttribute("class", "func-btns");

play.setAttribute("src", "../assets/play-icon.svg");
play.setAttribute("class", "play-icon");
pause.setAttribute("src", "../assets/pause-icon.svg");
pause.setAttribute("class", "pause-icon");

const playFnc = e => {
  myaudio.play();
  wavesurfer.play();
};
const pauseFnc = e => {
  myaudio.pause();
  wavesurfer.pause();
};

playBtn.onclick = playFnc;
pauseBtn.onclick = pauseFnc;

playBtn.appendChild(play);
pauseBtn.appendChild(pause);


btnDiv.appendChild(playBtn);
btnDiv.appendChild(pauseBtn);
trackContainer.appendChild(trackLabel);

trackContainer.appendChild(btnDiv);
trackContainer.appendChild(audio);
trackContainer.appendChild(waveDiv);
trackContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
soundClips.appendChild(trackContainer);



var blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
  type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"
});
audioChunks = [];
var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audio.src = audioURL;
var myaudio = new Audio(audioURL);

console.log(audioChunks);
deleteButton.onclick = e => {
  var evtTgt = e.target;
  evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
};


var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: ".waveform",
  waveColor: "#D81E5B",
  progressColor: "white",
  barGap: "4",
  barWidth: "3",
  barheight: "1",
  height: "100",
  scrollParent: false,
  cursorWidth: "0",
  interact: "true"
});

wavesurfer.load(audioURL);
```

};
}[This is what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5406.png)

[This is what i'm wanting the result to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amx1s.png)

[This is the waveform being injected into the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4nL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the article element and it's content into an array then appendChild to a parent div within a loop which added the new audio recording above the older one on the page. [Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMSwj.png)